# Store session data in cookie to share between Java based and Nodejs based application

Tags: node.js, jsp, session, servlets

I am working on existing application which is java based and we are migrating one page to NodeJS based application. We are thinking to take following approach.

1. In the java server, at the end of response, just write session data which is required by both server in cookie in encrypted format
2. NodeJS server will read this cookie to get the session data if any and will also update this cookie if any common session data is modified

Not sure if this is ok approach. Please note; we don't want to use any database to store the session data (As don't want to make more change in existing java based web application)

Looking for advice on this approach.

Comment: hi, have you go any solutions yet? Facing same problem here. I'm going to implement common session operations in JAVA such as generate/update/delete/save session methods. So I can call these methods in my nodejs layer

Comment: no, we finally decided to move all the pages to node js. Not sure what should be optimal solution for this use case. However your approach is what we also thought. The method in JAVA should exposed as REST API and it should be called from browser bcz your node js server will not have same session id to call java server.

Comment: oo, I'm going to try this approach. BTW, the session operation API in JAVA will be accessed by nodejs, just read the session id generated by java, and send it do JAVA API. because some pages need auth validation before rendered to user , you know

Comment: ok. please post details here if it works for you or even doesn't work. I am sure many application does partial Nodejs migration and they will get benefit of your experiment:-)